# How to handle Image resize in a canvas at time of uploading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html5-canvas

I have some Image manipulation processes where **users upload an image and crop it**, then **download the cropped image**. I am using a **Jquery library** called Jcrop to crop Images after being upload. How can I fit this Image in a fix canvas or area ?

below in a demo you can upload any large image and see it cover all area,

I already tried to fix this with HTML height, width and with css, I am guessing image will resize during upload.

- I am trying to **fit the image to a fix area/resize**, so that image is very big or small cannot overflow outside canvas.
- While **fixing image resize there should be no affect on image x,y values for cropping**.

I am guessing I need to do something in `imageLoader.onchange`.

```js
var jcp;
var save = document.getElementById('save');
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
var img = document.getElementById("target");

imageLoader.onchange = function handleImage(e) {
  // handling our image picker <input>:
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    img.src = event.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}

save.onclick = function() {
  if (jcp && jcp.active) {
    var i = 0;
    for (area of jcp.crops) {
      i++;
      canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.setAttribute('width', area.pos.w);
      canvas.setAttribute('height', area.pos.h);
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(img, area.pos.x, area.pos.y, area.pos.w, area.pos.h, 0, 0, area.pos.w, area.pos.h);
      temp = document.createElement('a');
      temp.setAttribute('download', 'area' + i + '.jpg');
      temp.setAttribute('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg").replace("image/jpg", "image/octet-stream"));
      temp.click();
    }
  }
};

// cropping fucntion of Jquery Plugin
Jcrop.load('target').then(img => {
  jcp = Jcrop.attach(img, {
    multi: true
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Jcrop Example</title>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/jcrop@3.0.1/dist/jcrop.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jcrop@3.0.1/dist/jcrop.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div> <!-- upload button -->
    <button id="save">Save</button>
    <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" /> 
  </div>
  
  <div> <!-- appears here after upload -->
    <img id="target" style="background-size: cover !important;">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: not sure why you'd need jquery or a jquery plugin for this, since the canvas has been able to do this from day one. The [drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) function explicitly lets you say draw an image to fit an arbitrary box. And the [toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) function lets you turn the canvas into base64 image data for use outside the canvas. Both of which you already use. So what part isn't actually working?

Comment: using plugin to *crop image* multiple areas, also I have tried @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: But "cropping" is just "copying a rectangle of image data and then throwing away the old image data", which [getImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) is for.

Comment: Don't put code in comments. If your post is lacking detail precision, update your post and then comment about what you updated. Comments only really allow for short inline code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans edited with working fiddle where you can check multiple cropping is going but issue with large image as it covers all area

Comment: Right, so: getting a crop is just a matter of `getImageData()` with the crop's x/y/w/h values. You can then just draw that data onto a new canvas of the same dimensions as your crop. And you can then do whatever you want with that (temporary) new canvas, like turning it into an image that people download by using `toDataURL` on _that_ canvas.

Comment: I am a bit confused, I really appreciate and thankful if you can share a `code snippet` as per my code structure

Comment: If you switch your jsfiddle to a Stackoverflow [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/740553), that will facilitate writing an answer a lot better.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans as you suggested I made a working snippet

Comment: @tomalak I saw your works and expertise in Jcrop and canvas any suggestions ?

Comment: I've rewritten your snippet a little as an answer to both fix the problem, and tighten up the JS a bit.

Comment: Remember that part of using SO is upvoting and accepting answers after you get one or more answers=)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that neither `image/jpg` nor `image/octet-stream` are real mime types, so your `toDataURL` will go "that's not a real mime type, I'm creating a png", and even if you used the correct image mimetype, the subsequent link would make the browser go "that's not a real mimetype, I'm ignoring this href".

So, let's fix those, and then also use a bit of modern JS to tighten up this code a bit. And you'll notice that this doesn't auto-download, which is due to Stackoverflow security settings. However, if your run this locally or in a permissive code sandbox (like codepen.io) you'll see it doing exactly what it should be doing.

```js
let jcp; // assigned by Jcrop.load

const imageFormat = `image/jpeg`;
const octetType = `application/octet-stream`;
const create = (tag) => document.createElement(tag);

// save, imageLoader, and target are all auto-created because of their id attributes.

imageLoader.addEventListener(`change`, (e) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (evt) => {
    target.src = evt.target.result;
    save.classList.remove(`hidden`);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
});

save.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
  if (typeof jcp === `undefined` || !jcp.active) return;
  [...jcp.crops].forEach((area, i) => downloadCrop(area, i+1));
});

function downloadCrop(area, id) {
  const { x, y, w, h } = area.pos;
  const crop = create(`canvas`);
  crop.width = w;
  crop.height = h;
  const ctx = crop.getContext(`2d`);
  ctx.drawImage(target, x, y, w, h, 0, 0, w, h);
  triggerDownload(crop, id);
}

function triggerDownload(crop, id) {
  const a = create(`a`);
  const number = `${id}`.padStart(3, `0`);
  const link = crop.toDataURL(imageFormat).replace(imageFormat, octetType);
  a.download = `area-${number}.jpg`;
  a.href = link;
  a.click();
}

// cropping fucntion of Jquery Plugin
Jcrop.load('target').then(img => {
  jcp = Jcrop.attach(img, {
    multi: true
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Jcrop Example</title>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/jcrop@3.0.1/dist/jcrop.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jcrop@3.0.1/dist/jcrop.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" /> 
    <button id="save" class="hidden">Save crops</button>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img id="target" style="background-size: cover !important;">
  </div>
</body>
```

One of the things you'll want to make sure to do from now on is *always* declaring variables as such. Never just write `thing = ....` without a `let` or `const` in front of it, because that makes global variables, and global variables are bugs waiting to happen. Also, don't use `var`, it's the variable keyword from an older version of JS with rather unusual scoping rules, again basically introducing bugs waiting to happen. Use `let` if you need a variable that you're going to (re)assign later, and use `const` if you need a variable that you know will/should not change value at any point in the block that you declared it in.